# What manufacturing process is suited for production of the elastomer strip?

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, product-engineering

What manufacturing process should be adopted to manufacture a LEGO® compatible strip made by material which is rubber like?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary length, I believe hot-forming. Feed a rubber band into a system that runs it along a roller heated past the $T_g$ of the rubber that has the desired imprint etched into it, then cool it down as it leaves the forming roller.

The actual temperatures, tension values for the band and pressure required are up to you to figure out once you settle on a specific material.